# Passing additional reference parameters as arguments to a callback object in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, keyword-argument

I am using a library that takes some keyword arguments during the initialization of the object.  These keyword arguments define the callback objects/functions that are called when a specific event occurs.  The callback objects themselves need to reference the object that called them and have some additional data that comes from the class/object instance itself.
What I would like to do is pass a reference to another object into one of these call backs when initializing in order to avoid using a global variable.

How/where would I pass the reference to the object?  Do I need to subclass?  If I do need to subclass can I accomplish this without understanding the working behind the class/library?  I tried looking at the source to try and figure something out but unfortunately it's a bit past my understanding.

Example which will hopefully get my point across:

```
def One(eI):
    *...do some stuff...*

def Two(eI, data, ref_I_want_to_add):
    *do some other stuff*

ref_I_want_to_pass = anotherClass(diff_arg,diff_arg2):
    *...you know the deal...*


eI = exampleClass(argOne=One, ..., argN=N)
```

The first thing that comes to mind is to use something like

```
eI = exampleClass(argOne=One, argTwo=Two(ref_I_want_to_pass), ..., argN)
```

But that obviously doesnt work because I get a `TypeError: argTwo takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

---

---

More precisely I am using the websocket client library and in order to create a `WebSocketApp` object which handles the connection you instaniate the object with something like

```
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(uri, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_ping=on_ping)
```

now I have a function named `on_message` that handles the incoming messages and I told the `ws` object during instantiation of `WebSocketApp` that I would like to use that function to handle the incoming messages or rather what to do with them.

I would like to update another object when a new message comes in, now I can of course use a global variable for that but it doesn't seem like the right way to do it and it would be nice if I could pass a reference to that object when initializing a `WebSocketApp` object, with something like:

```
ws = websock.WebSocketApp(uri, on_message=on_message(ref_to_Obj), on_open=on_open, on_ping=on_ping)
```

But obviously that doesnt work because again I get a `TypeError: argTwo takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` error.

I'm not entirely sure how to do this.  Subclassing comes to mind but even then I'm kind of lost, I will admit that subclassing is a topic I need more work on, I get the idea behind it and can do all the basic  examples they use in tutorials but more complex classes can stump me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a local variable to be passed onto a function, you need to create a closure around that variable. We can do that with `lambda`.

```
eI = exampleClass(argOne=One, ..., argN=lambda x, y: N(x, y, ref_I_want_to_pass))
```

Comment: So your answer is apparently the right answer but for some reason I am having trouble getting lambda to work and had to use `partial` from `functools` but I accepted it as technically it is correct although I personally couldn't get it to work